# Can non-metallic cables pass through one large opening at top of electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

Does the 2014 NEC eliminate the need to secure each cable to the cabinet?
Or can all cables pass through one large opening at top of panel?

Answer (score 3):

No, the NEC did not eliminate the need to secure. Each cable must be secured at each box or cabinet. Accordingly each connector or cable clamp will be listed with its capacity. One large connector is not listed for many small cables.